# MyGeneration MYSQL connection error

Tags: c#, mysql, mygeneration

Iam using MyGeneration Doodads to connect to MySql DB 
i connect using microsoft ole db provider for odbc drivers but get the following error

> [System.ArgumentException] - The .Net Framework Data Provider for
>   OLEDB (System.Data.OleDb) does not support the Microsoft OLE DB
>   Provider for ODBC Drivers (MSDASQL). Use the .Net Framework Data
>   Provider for ODBC (System.Data.Odbc).

how can i solve this problem